# Equivalent of UIFont .withSize in NSFont

Tags: swift, nsfont

I am working on getting the HandyUIKit String extensions working with AppKit.

What is the equivalent for

```
var font : UIFont    
font.withSize(font.pointSize * scriptedTextSizeRatio)
```

in Appkit and NSFont?

```
var font : NSFont    
font.withSize(font.pointSize * scriptedTextSizeRatio)
```

Here is the code section I am working on:

```
 let capturedSubstring = unprocessedString.attributedSubstring(from: match.range(at: 1)).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
 let captureFullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: capturedSubstring.length)
 capturedSubstring.addAttribute(.font, value: font.withSize(font.pointSize * scriptedTextSizeRatio), range: captureFullRange)
```

Comment: AppKit in Cocoa?  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSFont` doesn't seem to have an equivalent method `withSize` like `UIFont`.

One solution would be to use:

```
var font: NSFont = ... // some font
var newFont = NSFont(descriptor: font.fontDescriptor, size: font.pointSize * scriptedTextSizeRatio)
```

Note that `newFont` will be optional so check the result as needed.